# How can I upload file in server on background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I upload a file in the background in flutter? Is it possible to use flutter_uploader? It seems like it is deprecated already.

I tried fluter_uploader but it looks like it is deprecated already. Is there any other package or option to use? Thank you!  The goal is once I uploaded, it will redirect to the home page, and the user can see the uploading status in the notification bar

Comment: user workmanager or background_fetch package to run any background tasks.
https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager
https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
FYI: please go through docs as IOS has limitation while performing background tasks

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do it using api for that you can use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File file) async {
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "file":
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:fileName),
    });
    response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
    return response.data['id'];
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //send user to another page
      print("Image Uploaded");
    } else {
     //try to send image again
      print("Upload Failed");
    }
}
```